# Returning matching value from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to return a currency symbol and currency code based on $ProductCurrency whose value is the one of the currencies in the first column in the array, this is the code that I have;

```
<?php

    $currency_symbols = array (

        array ('australian dollar','&#36;','aud'),
        array ('brazilian real','&#82;&#36;','brl'),
        array ('canadian dollar','&#36;','cad'),
        array ('czech koruna','&#75;&#269;','czk'),
        array ('danish krone','&#107;&#114;','dkk'),
        array ('euro','&#8364;','euro'),
        array ('pound sterling','&#163;','gbp'),
        array ('hong kong dollar','&#36;','hkd'),
        array ('hungarian forint','&#70;&#116;','huf'),
        array ('israeli new sheqel','&#8362;','ils'),
        array ('japanese yen','&#165;','jpy'),
        array ('malaysian ringgit','&#82;&#77;','myr'),
        array ('mexican peso','&#36;','mxn'),
        array ('norwegian krone','&#107;&#114;','nok'),
        array ('new zealand dollar','&#36;','nzd'),
        array ('philippine peso','&#8369;','php'),
        array ('polish zloty','&#122;&#322;','pln'),
        array ('russian ruble','&#1088;&#1091;&#1073;','rub'),
        array ('singapore dollar','&#36;','sgd'),
        array ('swedish krona','&#107;&#114;','sek'),
        array ('swiss franc','&#67;&#72;&#70;','chf'),
        array ('thai baht','&#3647;','thb'),
        array ('turkish lira','&#8356;','try'),
        array ('taiwan new dollar','&#78;&#84;&#36;','twd'),
        array ('us dollar','&#36;','usd'),
    );

    $ProductCurrency = 'australian dollar';
    $CurrencySymbol = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][1];
    $CurencyCode = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][2];

?>
```

but the code is returning nothing for the $CurrencySymbol for which I was expecting `&#36;` and $CurrencyCode for which I was expecting 'aud', variables, what am I missing?

Comment: what's `get_field` ? are you using wp ?

Comment: *"what am I missing?"* - more (relevant) code. In the meantime, see if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php returns anything.

Comment: Yes it's WordPress, get_field('product_currency') return a a user choice which is based on the same list as in column 1 in the array e.g. 'australian dollar', or 'brazillian real', this works fine so you can assume $ProductCurrency = australian dollar.

Comment: @Fred-ii- more code such as? also no errors are reported.

Comment: can the array  be changed ? I don't see too much logic on it.

Comment: arrays start at 0; you sure you didn't mean `[0]` and `[1]`? or are you not echoing those somewhere (else)? as it stands, you're only declaring them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think so, e.g. if $Product_Currency = australian dollar, for currency symbol I want to do find australian dollar in the array and return the value in column 2 (&#36;) which is [1] wouldn't [0] just be australian dollar?

Comment: @PedroLobito yes it can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$ProductCurrency` as a key to find the symbol and code, for this to work you would have to format your array as follow :

```
<?php

$currency_symbols = array (

    'australian dollar' => array ('&#36;','aud'),
    'brazilian real' => array ('&#82;&#36;','brl'),
    // ...
);

$ProductCurrency = get_field('product_currency');
$CurrencySymbol = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][0];
$CurencyCode = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][1];
```

You should probably [check if the key exists](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in your array before you assign $CurrencySymbol and $CurrencyCode.

If you want / have to keep the $currency_symbols array as is, you can retrieve the symbol and code this way :

```
$ProductCurrency = get_field('product_currency');
$filteredSymbols = array_filter($currency_symbols, function ($row) use ($ProductCurrency) {
    return $row[0] === $ProductCurrency;
});
$CurrencySymbol = $filteredSymbols[0][1];
$CurrencyCode = $filteredSymbols[0][2];
```

This is less efficient and, to be honest, quite dirty. You should, at the very least, check that $filteredSymbols is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much logic on your array, specially if you need to search for a specific `key`, here's a different approach:

```
<?php
$currency_symbols = array(
    "australian dollar" => array ('&#36;','aud'),
    "brazilian real" => array ('&#82;&#36;','brl'),
    "canadian dollar" => array ('&#36;','cad'),
    "czech koruna" => array ('&#75;&#269;','czk'),
    "danish krone" => array ('&#107;&#114;','dkk'),
    "euro" => array ('&#8364;','euro'),
    "pound sterling" => array ('&#163;','gbp'),
    "hong kong dollar" => array ('&#36;','hkd'),
    "hungarian forint" => array ('&#70;&#116;','huf'),
    "israeli new sheqel" => array ('&#8362;','ils'),
    "japanese yen" => array ('&#165;','jpy'),
    "malaysian ringgit" => array ('&#82;&#77;','myr'),
    "mexican peso" => array ('&#36;','mxn'),
    "norwegian krone" => array ('&#107;&#114;','nok'),
    "new zealand dollar" => array ('&#36;','nzd'),
    "philippine peso" => array ('&#8369;','php'),
    "polish zloty" => array ('&#122;&#322;','pln'),
    "russian ruble" => array ('&#1088;&#1091;&#1073;','rub'),
    "singapore dollar" => array ('&#36;','sgd'),
    "swedish krona" => array ('&#107;&#114;','sek'),
    "swiss franc" => array ('&#67;&#72;&#70;','chf'),
    "thai baht" => array ('&#3647;','thb'),
    "turkish lira" => array ('&#8356;','try'),
    "taiwan new dollar" => array ('&#78;&#84;&#36;','twd'),
    "us dollar" => array ('&#36;','usd')
);

$ProductCurrency = get_field('product_currency'); //us dollar
$CurrencySymbol = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][0];
$CurencyCode = $currency_symbols[$ProductCurrency][1];
echo $CurrencySymbol; //&#36;
echo $CurencyCode; //usd
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/5VQneH)

Comment: That's a lot of $currency_symbols

Comment: If you prefer less `$currency_symbols` , check the updated answer, it does exactly the same as before without as much code.